# Token appears in address bar when using OpenID/IdentityServer and redirecting to different page

Tags: angular, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 and Angular 2 and the angular-oauth2-oidc library. When I authenticate to Identity Server and redirect to a different page it puts the token in the address bar, if I redirect back to the same page the login was initiated from then the address bar is fine.

```
public redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:4200/requests';
this.oAuthService.redirectUri = this._configuration.redirect_uri;

Address Bar = http://localhost:4200/requests#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Im...
```

Has anyone see anything like this before? Any idea where to begin looking at how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal intended behavior. It is standard to send the token through as a hash/uri fragment.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765619/how-exactly-hash-fragment-based-security-works) post can clear it up for you.