# What is hash fragment referring to in the following text?

Tags: authentication

In the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387698/why-is-there-an-authorization-code-flow-in-oauth2-when-implicit-flow-works-s) they use the term hash fragment. I am not quite sure what they mean by that. Are they referring to the text after a hash in a url?

e.g. `www.someurl.com#somefragment`

The blurb I am looking at in the article is below

> In the implicit flow the access token is passed directly as a **hash**
>   **fragment** (not as a URL parameter). One important thing about hash
>   fragment is that, once you follow a link containing a hash fragment,
>   only the browser is aware of the hash fragment. Browsers will pass the
>   hash fragment directly to the destination webpage (the redirect URI /
>   the client's webpage). Hash fragment have the following properties:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. They refer to the URL part after the `#` character.

In `example.com#state=dJfw&access_token=lkTyd234AsdF` the hash fragment (fragment component) would be:

```
state=dJfw&access_token=lkTyd234AsdF
```

This is used by the OAuth2 implicit grant to deliver the response data. In the specification, the terminology used is either fragment component or fragment.

In contrast, the authorization code grant would deliver the information in the query part of the URL, `example.com?state=asdTwe3SD&code=kjh56Sdgv`.