# Authenticating using Auth2 when there are several resources

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

I need to implement a single sign on of a user, which can get services from several different services.

When there was only a single service, the user could log in from the client side, send the request to a backend, gets a URL back to a JWT token issuer server, from which he can get a token which he sends back to the BE and he is now authenticated.

What is now changing, is that he needs to get more services. Each service has its own frontend and backend, but everyone are using the same issuer. Meaning there are both services with FE and BE, and also there is another general BE for the authentication.

What is the correct flow to authenticate in the scenario? Can the general BE issue a token for the client for each of the required services? Or should the BE respond the client with the services's BE url and let the client itself send an authentication token response from each service? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean OpenID Connect, since OAuth2.0 is not used for authentication and does not require the use of JWTs. Also, in your scenario there are not multiple resources, but multiple clients / relying parties.

Using the OpendID Connect Implicit flow, the issuer will eventually send an id token (JWT) to the user's browser. This JWT can be used to authenticate to a service. Each JWT will contain an `aud` (audience) claim to identify the service it should be used for.

Using the Authorization Code flow, the issuer will eventually send an authorization code to the user's browser. The user will send the code to a service, and the service will send the code plus its client id to the issuer in exchange for an id token (JWT) and an access token.

In both cases, the service identifies the end user using the `iss` (issuer) claim, and verifies the JWT by checking the signature, expiry and audience.

Comment: Meaning it's ok if the client sends the request for token for the services and it's also OK if the BE sends the request for the token? Or is there somehow a preference in this case?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387698/why-is-there-an-authorization-code-flow-in-oauth2-when-implicit-flow-works-s