# What is the correct Redirect URI for Single Page App (SPA) runs inside a web browser for Oauth2 Auth Code Flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application, pkce

Say a SPA hosted in spa.com is loaded by user in user.com and uses oauth2 server oauth2.com for authentication through auth code flow (optional with PKCE). after user authenticated, oauth2.com would send the auth code back to the web browser and instructs it to redirect to the "redirect URI" registered with the app. now since SPA runs entirely inside the web browser, which can be anywhere, what the redirect URI should the SPA sent to oauth2.com to start with?

1. http://localhost : suppose to be just for local testing
2. its own address (user.com) : will not work since it is not registered
3. spa.com : SPA runs entirely in browser, not connected to spa.com

i know #1 and #3 do work but can't figure out why (#3). please advise what is wrong or missing with my understanding. thanks in advance!

Comment: This related question might also help you wrap your head around the security measures around OAuth2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387698/why-is-there-an-authorization-code-flow-in-oauth2-when-implicit-flow-works-s?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The redirect URI for an SPA is usually the public URL of the app itself, so in your case this will be a value similar to one of these. On a developer PC this might be a localhost URL but I would think of it as a deployed URL and try to use proper domain names:

- https://myspa.com
- https://myspa.com/myapp

The technique for an SPA is then  to see if you are receiving a login response as part of the main page load. See the call to **handleLoginResponse** in [this source file of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/app/app.ts).